# Thunderbird: Message filter for time

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

**My need in short**: In Thunderbird (currently using version 100.0b2) I'd like to define a message filter that filters messages for a given time(slot) (e.g. between 01:00 AM and 05:00 AM).

**Background** is that some (monitoring/test/productive/...) systems send emails all day and most of the nightly emails I don't want to have in my Thunderbird inbox, but as a history in some log folders. Outside the timeslot 01:00 AM - 05:00 AM I want to see the same type of emails in my Thunderbird inbox. So filtering by body or subject or sender or receiver is no option.

This is a "Date" header from one email I want to filter:
[image: Date header from Thunderbird email]

**What I tried**: I tried to define a custom property ("Tools" > "Message filters" > "New" > "Customize..." > "New message header"="Date" > "Add"), but Thunderbird just offers filter operators "is", "isn't", "is before" and "is after" for date values, but no time restriction.
[image: Thunderbird with Date filter]

**Question**: How can I filter by time (without date)?